# Ubuntu desktop 22.04.3 LTS not loading after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 22.04, ubuntu-gnome

I am dual booting windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I installed windows 11 first and then Ubuntu with fast boot and secure boot off. The desktop loads with default graphic drivers but not with nvidia proprietary driver. I am using a Zepherus G14 GA401QH with AMD processor and 1650 nvidia graphic driver. I tried looking on the nvidia forums and followed the steps given there but I wasn't able to get the OS working. I have created a forum post there but no response till now. I have attached the nvidia report here [Nvidia forum post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-blank-screen-with-blinking-cursor/268673). Please do let me know what I can do next. FYI I am new to Linux if that explains any mistakes I have made.

Comment: How exactly did you install the Nvidia drivers?  The restricted repository (Software & Updates) should be enabled, sudo update, then the Software & Updates "Additional Drivers" tab should show choices. Or use ubuntu-drivers. Any other way, even if you get it to work, will likely fail upon the first kernel update.

Comment: oh, I directly went to additional drivers and installed it. The other way I tried is through tty terminal in the blinking cursor screen. I uninstalled the drivers and reinstalled it via apt. I tried following this as well. [link](https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-linux/)